# How to clear the pygame cache event in python

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

I'm coding a little game for a school project: a basket game.

When the user clicks somewhere in the screen, the script gives an initial speed and angle to the ball and the ball starts its path.

I've got a problem: if the user starts to click while the ball has not ended its path yet, pygame saves the click and automatically launches a second path when the first one is over.

I'm looking for a method or anything to clear the event's cache while the path isn't ended.

The pygame.event cache seems to be active whatever...
That's what I already did :

```
if clic==False : #bool who blocks
        if event.type==MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and  event.button==1:
            clic=True
            ball move
            ...
            clic=False
```

I could have misplaced the bool, but when clic is Flase again all the clicks stocked in the pygame.event start their paths.

If you want I can share with you the whole code but It's written with French comments and there are a lot of pictures that need to be with the script file.

I'm looking for cleaning the cache or just pausing the saving process while my ball is in the air.

Comment: You can just use some booleans to keep track of weather the ball has ended it path.

Answer (score 1):

I've found the answer sorry for disturbing you.

For the one looking for it, there it is :

```
if event.type==MOUSEBUTTON ...
   ball move
   ...
   pygame.event.clear()
```

Answer (score 0):

I can help you with the code becasue you havent included any but here is the basic idea. Make a boolean called `can_shoot` to keep track of what the ball is doing. Once the player shoots set it to False. Keep checking if the ball has completed its path every single frame and as soon as it does, set `can_shoot` to true again.

```
if can_shoot:
     #code to move the ball 
     #condition to change can_shoot to False
```